# "Multiple pass" RegEx for fixing space indentations

Tags: regex

Searched and found some apparently similar questions, that weren't quite.

I often find myself needing to replace leading 4-space indentations with tabs.  I always do this with RegEx `^(\t*) {4}`, replacing with `$1\t`.  And then I just do multiple passes to catch nested indents.  It works, it's easy.  But I'm wondering, is it possible to write a RegEx that can do this in one pass (to handle nested indents)?

**EDIT**

Apologies for lack of input/output examples, I was in a hurry.  Here's an example, let `s` mean `space` and `t` mean `tab`:

```
SMA
ssssRTP
ssssssssATR
ssssssssOLN
ssssOWH
ssssERE
TOGO
```

Output:

```
SMA
tRTP
ttATR
ttOLN
tOWH
tERE
TOGO
```

Essentially, the RegEx would need to allow for arbitrarily deeply nested chunks of 4 spaces.  It does *not* need to allow for tabs following spaces in the initial input.

PCRE

Comment: what is the input and expected output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12807987/62576 might give you an idea or two (although it deals with indents using spaces).

Comment: You need to provide some examples and specify which language you're using for regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(^\t*|\G) {4}` replace with `$1\t` or `(^|\G)( {4}|\t)` replace with `\t`. You should use multiline mode.

### How this works:

`^\t*` — this match start of string followed by any numbers of tabs.
`\G` — this match end of previous match.
`​ {4}` — this match four spaces.

So this regular expression match four spaces at the start of string or four spaces following four spaces already matched by this regular expression.

Comment: Your first suggestion is perfect. It would be good if you could provide at least a terse explanation of how/why this works for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Tested this with .NET's regex engine. JavaScript's (at least Mozilla's) won't work, though; it relies on lookbehind, which isn't available. PCRE wants fixed-length lookbehinds, so this won't work there either, unfortunately.

```
(?<=^( {4}|\t)*) {4}
```

Basic idea is to match four spaces preceded by the beginning of a line *plus* all the spots where a previous match would naturally go. Since replacement is done atomically, there's no chance of missing such a spot; all such matches are gathered at once. Then make sure you're using `Multiline` flag and replace with a single tab character and you're good to go.

Test data, which is just random pseudocode in a vaguely Pythonesque style:

```
    def a:
        return true
          # comment     with embedded        spaces etc.
```

Comment: it is not working for string, contains <TAB><8 SPACES>

Comment: @RubenKazumov Post some sample data you're working with (that gets messed up) and your regex engine in the question.

Comment: @RubenKazumov Note that regexr.com explicitly won't support lookbehinds, so running it there is useless. I've copied the sample data into the question and am about to update with a tweaked regex.

Comment: @ Nathan Tuggy: I am apologies! Sorry for that!

Comment: @RubenKazumov http://regexhero.net/tester/ should work for .NET-based regex testing. I was just using PowerShell though.

Comment: Can't this be simplified to `(?<=^( {4}|\t)*) {4}`?  Regardless, Sublime Text reports `invalid lookbehind assertion encountered`.

Comment: @Madbreaks: Yeah, that's because (upon looking up the PCRE docs) only fixed-length lookbehinds are supported. .NET is more flexible here. But you're right about the simplification; I had left the grouping in as an artifact of the various changes the expression went through.